# Вернуть дату зная день недели

Tags: php

Помогите с решением задачи на PHP

Имеется текущая дата например(17/03/2014) день недели Понедельник.

А также я знаю следующий день недели (Пятница),(саму дату не знаю, только день недели)
Как узнать от текущей даты, Дату которая будет в Пятницу?

Пример.
Знаю  18/03/2014 (вторник)  нужно получить дату понедельника. => должно получиться  24/03/2014

Знаю  31/03/2014 (Понедельник)  нужно получить дату среды. => должно получиться  02/04/2014

Знаю  21/03/2014 (Пятница)  нужно получить дату понедельник. => должно получиться  24/03/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следующий вторник от текущей даты

```
$nextTuesday = strtotime('next tuesday');
echo date( "Y-m-d", $nextTuesday );
```

read about [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function :)

Comment: нет, мне не нужен следующий вторник, мне нужна дата например Пятницы.

Comment: неслАбо, гуглим словарик английского языка и узнаем, что пятница это friday... или вы совсем предлагаете за вас сделать? :)

Comment: 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday',
спасибо большое)

Comment: Да не за что)))